# When this CD is spun so fast that it shatters, why does the warped shape move slower than the surface?

Tags: kinematics

In [this video](https://youtu.be/zs7x1Hu29Wc?t=6m54s) where a CD is spun abnormally fast to the point of shattering, one notices from the writing on the CD that the surface is spinning faster than the warp "shape" is. In other words, the shape the CD has warp into is moving in a circle, but not quite as fast as the surface of the CD. What's the explanation behind this de-synchronization?

I would expect the warp shape to either not spin much at all, or spin at the same speed as the surface of the CD.

Comment: it looks like that the deformations are vibrational modes, if so they should travel at the sound speed of the CD, not at the rotating speed

Comment: Although cracks travel at the speed of sound in the medium, and from the rest of the video this is clearly much much faster :) The waves are travelling at a much slower speed. Observing the video it seems to be 5 to 6 times slower than the rotation of the disk. If I can come up with a reason for this I'll post an answer.