# Why does a rotating flexible disk have wave shape?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, continuum-mechanics, centrifugal-force, stress-strain

I found [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs7x1Hu29Wc&feature=youtu.be) on which they shatter CD with a high RPM tool. Before the CD shatters it has a wavy shape, so I guess an axial force shatters the CD instead of a radial force, probably some kind of vibration. Am I right, or something completely different happens here?

Comment: similar is [When this CD is spun so fast that it shatters, why does the warped shape move slower than the surface?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256226)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a nice phenomenon!

Because of the centrifugal force, the disk expands in the radial direction (this is an axisymmetric problem).

Because the material is incompressible, it has to contract in the orthogonal direction. This is known as [Poisson's effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio) in solid mechanics. Also, those stresses are called "hoop stress".

This compressive hoop stress leads to buckling because a disk is a thin structure :)

Comment: Does the disk break because of this hoop stress?

Comment: I had a first answer to that excellent follow up question, but watching the video more closely changed my mind.
I think that the fracture is initiated the crest of a wave, and it first starts in the radial direction. This means that the stress causing the fracture it orthoradial, and is probably due to the bending of the disk. This is why it starts at the crest, it is the location of the highest extensive stress (bending causes both extensive and compressive stresses if you look along the thickness).
This means that it breaks because it bends, you can try it by bending a disk yourself.

Comment: I suspected that too. Just to mention, one sample usually does not proof anything.  :-)